# fixed income calculator

Tags: calculation, fixed-income

where can I find a fixed income investment calculator?
How much income can I expect monthly if I try to live off the interest alone?
Are there any penalties for switching investment strategies?

Comment: can you please edit this to be only one clear question?  If you keep the first, what does 450k get you in fixed income, you'll need to tell us if you plan to withdraw principal or only "interest", and if so for how long do you want the money to last.  Country would also help to give an idea of current interest rates.

Comment: Your age and country might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a very full-featured fixed income bond calculator at http://www.ftlabs.com/WebFISC .  It covers US treasury, agency, corporate, municipal, and CD securities - including fixed rate, callable, step-coupon, zero-coupon, etc.